# How to add line breaks in semantic ui

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui, line-breaks, semantic-ui-react

Hello everyone I am using semantic ui for my website
but the problem is that in the input line breaks does not comes and i am not using  tag of html i am using <Form.TextArea> of semantic ui so any one pls guid me how can i add line breaks when user pressed enter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Qds.png)

And please also visit my website to type and read interesting stories written by people : https://kiosrt.herokuapp.com

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok do u have the solution

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. You need add some codes and do not use images. you can edit you question with Edit button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.